# bar code into a window wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the bar code into a window wpf application,It is not showing pop up    "MessageBox.Show("Item Not Found");" when item not exist into db

I have implemneted the log, according to log it is going into else loop, but not showing message box.

Please let me know your thoughts for the same

I am using below code:

```
    private void txtBarcode_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        string urlLogPath = @"C:\11VideoWorking\Log\CashDrawerLog.txt";           
        try
        {
            if (txtBarcode.Text.Length == 13)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(urlLogPath, "Befor Get Product \n");
                objProductList = ObjGasLogic.GetSearchedProduct();
                File.AppendAllText(urlLogPath, "Befor Product Check  \n");
                if (objProductList != null)
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(urlLogPath, "Before Condition \n");
                    if (objProductList.Any(CheckProduct => CheckProduct.Barcode == txtBarcode.Text.Trim()))
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText(urlLogPath, "Item Found \n");
                        objProductDetails = objProductList.Where(Product => Product.Barcode == txtBarcode.Text.Trim()).SingleOrDefault();
                        objProductDetails.Quantity = 0;
                        BindCurrentlySelectedProduct();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText(urlLogPath, "Item Not Found ,\n");
                        MessageBox.Show("Item Not Found");
                        File.AppendAllText(urlLogPath, "After Item Not Found \n");
                    }
                    //ClearCurrentSelectedProductDetails();                           
                }
                else
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(urlLogPath, "6 \n");
                    MessageBox.Show("Item Not Found");
                    ClearCurrentSelectedProductDetails();                       
                }
            }
            File.AppendAllText(urlLogPath, "End of Try \n");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ObjExceptionLogic.LogException(ex.Message, Convert.ToInt32(User.Instance.User_ID));
            File.AppendAllText(urlLogPath, "In catch\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried setting a break point in the method and debugging through the code?

Comment: Yes I have already used, there is no exception

Answer (score 0):

ok i have tried to clean up your code a little bit to reduce the [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)

```
private void txtBarcode_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtBarcode.Text.Length == 13)
            {
                var product = ObjGasLogic.GetProduct(txtBarcode.Text.Trim());

                if (product != null)
                {
                    objProductDetails = product;
                    objProductDetails.Quantity = 0;
                    BindCurrentlySelectedProduct();                                             
                }
                else
                {                        
                    MessageBox.Show("Item Not Found");
                    ClearCurrentSelectedProductDetails();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ObjExceptionLogic.LogException(ex.Message, Convert.ToInt32(User.Instance.User_ID));                
        }
    }
```

this will require you to create a new method in the you objGasLogic class

```
ObjGasLogic.GetProduct(txtBarcode.Text.Trim())
```

to take a barcode but should reduce the complexity of this method.

with this implemented you should have a better idea of where the problem is, i think writing to a log file here is a little unnecessary and a break point should be sufficient.

Comment: I have implemented the logs because I need to test it on client server, where I can- not debug the code.

Comment: so you are saying it works locally but not remotely? by all means you can but in those debugging logs while figuring it out. you can also just do remote debugging where you can attach to a process on another machine, if you have the privileges that is.

Comment: It is working properly when I debug the code, It is also going in else loop where I have shown pop up 'item not found'in case of item not found, but it is not showing pop up message on screen, I am confuse what is happening here, there is also no exception.

Comment: are you using the message box at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox?

Comment: Yes it is System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox

Comment: have you tried with the system.windows.messagebox instead to see if that one works. if not there may be a problem on your deploy machine or how you deployed it. Maybe you could deploy to another machine and try it on that

Comment: Yes it is System.Windows.MessageBox

Comment: It is window application,application running by Exe, I am getting this problem with bar code scanner,I do not have scanner to test this